# Do goods on tables and other stuff respawn?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I stole a ton of ingots and stuff from the blacksmith in Solitude, and I really want to know if that stuff will ever regenerate or if I should just forget the place.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, after 10 consecutive in-game days of not entering the [Blacksmith's shop](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Solitude_Blacksmith), the contents of the cell will reset and everything inside will [respawn](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Respawn).